# Rails migration won't run, no error thrown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration

Here's a simple migration I'd like to run :

```
class AddTimeOfRevisionToBrandWikis < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :brand_wikis, :time_of_revision, :datetime
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :brand_wikis, :time_of_revision
  end
end
```

Here's what I get when I try to run it :

```
$ rake db:migrate
(in /Users/kouak/Documents/workspace/wtb)
You have 1 pending migrations:
  20100404115341 AddTimeOfRevisionToBrandWikis
Run "rake db:migrate" to update your database then try again.
```

What's wrong with rake db:migrate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that migration class.

That error is generated by the rake task `db:abort_if_pending_migrations` which is called by `db:test:prepare` which is called by all the test tasks.  Somehow you've created a dependency for `db:migrate` that runs the `db:abort_if_pending_migrations`.  Look in your `Rakefile`.

Comment: Had this in a custom rcov.rake file. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

check your schema version and also last migration number the one you running now must be last.